# Python .read() doesn't read CSV correctly into string

Tags: python, amazon-mws

I am trying to push a tab delimited .txt file to Amazon using the MWS Api. The code below works:

```
    from boto.mws import connection
    import time

    # Amazon US MWS ID
    MarketPlaceID = 'mpid'
    MerchantID = 'merchantid'
    AccessKeyID = 'akid'
    SecretKey = 'secretkey'

    conn = connection.MWSConnection(
        aws_access_key_id=AccessKeyID,
        aws_secret_access_key=SecretKey,
        Merchant=MerchantID)

    feed = conn.submit_feed(
        FeedType='_POST_FLAT_FILE_PRICEANDQUANTITYONLY_UPDATE_DATA_',
        PurgeAndReplace=False,
        MarketplaceIdList=[MarketPlaceID],
        content_type='text/tab-separated-values',
        FeedContent="""SKU  QUANTITY
ABC 123"""
    )
```

With the method above, ABC's quantity gets set to 123. However, when I try to read the same data from a tab delimited file into feed_dat and pass feed_dat into FeedContent, I get an error stating that my headers are off.

```
feed_content = open('/Scripts/data.txt', 'rb')
print feed_content.read()
feed_dat = feed_content.read()
```

I have a feeling the .read() method is corrupting my tab delimited data. I can copy/paste the first couple of rows and push them through the API by wrapping the data in triple quotes, but I can't seem to read the tab file to a variable and push it that way. I have also tried encoding the file using .encode('utf-8') with no luck. Your input is appreciated!

Thank you,

C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `feed_content.read()` twice. The first time, the entire content is read and the cursor now points to the end of the file. Calling `feed_content.read()` again will return an empty string, because the end of the file has already been reached.

Please see the documentation for [`read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) for an example of this.

An easy fix would be to move the `print` after the assignment, to avoid attempting to call `read()` twice:

```
feed_content = open('/Scripts/data.txt', 'rb')
feed_dat = feed_content.read()
print feed_dat # print has been moved after the assignment
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! I found another workaround for people who may be having issues that are unrelated. You can pull the data from the web: response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.website.com/output/nvt.txt')
feed_dat = response.read()